# How to generate a websocket error

Tags: javascript, websocket, integration-testing

I am writing a library that has server and client components that use websockets as the transport. I'm testing on a variety of browsers and need to test some behaviors tied to errors and the sockets unexpectedly closing.

Is there a way to cause an error in the websocket (aside from trying to connect to an invalid url/non-websocket server)?

**NOTE:** I am **not** unit testing. I need to test how clients interact with servers, within different browsers, so mocking the websockets is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

You could either close the connection from the server side (in a non-graceful manner) or you might be able to stick a proxy in the middle (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and use that to clip the socket if possible.